# Red Gate SQL Compare vs. VS2010 Ultimate

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, version-control, sqlcompare

I used to use SQL2000 and Red Gate SQL Compare 3.2 and I was a happy camper. I wouldn't worry about tracking the changes that I make to the dev database until all the coding was done and I needed to compile a list of scripts to bring the prod db in sync with the prod.

This is where SQL Compare and to some degree, SQL Data Compare, were invaluable in

1. pointing out the differences and even more importantly,
2. helping me generate the SQLs to bring the prod db in sync with the dev db.

I see that VS2010 Ultimate allows me to compare two schemas, but does do #2? I believe it is suppose to but it ain't obvious to me how to do that.

Any kick in the right direction would be an immediate vote up  or better. ty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it does (2). To achieve this, run the comparison (Data/Schema Compare/New Schema Comparison), choose the objects you want to update, and then right click on the grid or go to the Data/Schema Compare menu and select Refresh Update script. If you can't see an upgrade script now, select Show Schema Update Script which is in the same menu.

If you want a more user-friendly and versatile tool, please consider trying SQL Compare 8! (I'm the product manager)

Comment: Red Gates tools are very good. I wish that I had a place to test your source control for SQL. I don't know how well your product is doing, but from my perspective, people aren't that interested in database source control aside from, at best, manually scripting to text and putting the text file into source control. This leaves much to be desired in my opinion and I am real really surprised at how so many people are happy with that. A lot of people have to be forced to use a good tool before they realize its value. Then you cant take it away from them.

Comment: @Velika - Perceptive comments! SQL Source Control's adoption has actually been remarkably good, and it's growing faster than any other SQL tool we've ever released. There's no doubt that database source control is in its infancy and still a way off being mainstream, but I think it's only a matter of time. We've certainly found that once users actually try out the tool, they're sold on its value. The hurdle is gaining awareness of the tool's abilities in the first place.

Comment: Check out this screen shot of my DB Compare utility that I wrote for personal use. Note the date in the lower left hand corner from the video screen cast. At the time, I couldn't find any db compare tools. http://content.screencast.com/users/Dokmanc/folders/Jing/media/8f49eaba-a0e8-4e14-9753-68b04177fb0c/2011-12-09_2309.png. I love utilities and you guys created a lot of the stuff I did and planned to create but never did.

Answer (score 4):

Caution plug,I wrote a blog entry to compare SQL Data in VS2010 Ultimate and Premium that you might wanna check out http://zubairdotnet.blogspot.com/2010/07/fun-with-vs2010-ultimate-comparing-sql.html

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, this tool in VS2010 Ultimate will only work with SQL Server 2005 and 2008.  I tried yesterday to do a compare between my production SQL 2000 instance and a dev 2008 instance, and it flat-out said it will not work with anything prior to 2005.  RedGate Compare, of course, had no issues at all.

Answer (score 3):

Drop every thing, and try **SQL Server Data Tools** October 2013 release for **Visual Studio 2012**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/tools.aspx, choose 'Get It' and then 'Download SSDT for Visual Studio 2012', or you can go straight there on:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015

It has Schema Compare and Data Compare, and even allows SQL Server 2014 CTP2 connections.